# isEqual is not working properly in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code looks like proper but isEqual used to compare two object is not working. i'm new to iOS. there is no much resource to check. [box2 isEqual:box1] is always gives me No. but it supposed to give Yes. anything wrong in my code, please suggest me the correct thing. thanks in advance. expecting best suggestion .

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Box:NSObject
{
    double length;   // Length of a box
    double breadth;  // Breadth of a box
    double height;   // Height of a box
}
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) double height; // Property

-(double) volume;
//-(id)initWithLength:(double)l andBreadth:(double)b;
@end

@implementation Box

@synthesize height; 

-(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   {
   length = 2.0;
   breadth = 3.0;
   }

   return self;
}

-(double) volume
{
   return length*breadth*height;
}

@end
@class Box;
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   Box *box1 = [[Box alloc]init];    // Create box1 object of type Box
   Box *box2 = [[Box alloc]init];
   NSLog (@"hello world");
   box1.height = 5.0;
   NSLog (@"%ld",[box1 volume]);

   if([box2 isEqual:box1])
   {
   NSLog(@"%b",[box2 isEqual:box1]);
   }
   [pool drain];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: They will not be ever equals as they are two different instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override isEqual method in your object.

e.g. in your "@implementation Box"

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[Box class]]) {
        Box*box = (Box*)object;
        return self.height == box.height; // compare heights values
    }
    return [super isEqual:object];
}
```

Comment: For clarification: He has to do the same with `length` (or `width`). However I recommend to add a `-isEqualToBox:` method, because one need it often and you can use it from `-isEqual:` without casting.

Comment: Thanks @kabarga , but i need to know is it possible without overriding it ? if it possible then how ? if its not can you please explain why ?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: mostly right. It was just an example. He can add more stuff to compare, it depends on his opinion, when it is true. I think cleaner to use isEqual since you don't need to add additional method isEqualToBox to .h file if any.

Comment: @kabarga In most cases adding a method to the interface is no caveat, but additional help to the class' user, isn't it?

Comment: @Chetak: Lets say you have some class "Car". And you created 2 instances: car1, car2. these are different cars, and you can only say that [car1 isEqual: car1] since this is the same car. To compare cars then you need to add some specific checks. What means that the cars are the same? they have to have the same color, same engine etc...So, basically if you want to compare your boxes you need to compare params that you think is right to compare.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: I did not say that your suggestion was wrong. I just said that to override the method is a bit cleaner at least for me.

Comment: @kabarga in my example i'm creating instance of same class, both share the same property so why i need to override it ?

Comment: @Chetak: share? in your example you created 2 different instances of Box. e.g. if you do box1.height = 5 then box2.height will be different.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: on the other hand we have like isEqualToString methods. so, this is "up to developers" decision.

Comment: This is what I wanted to express with "often needed". (Of course, if you need check on equity at all, what is rare.) However, it is not important.

Answer (score 0):

isEqual: works just fine and as documented, but not as you expected.

isEqual: is a property of NSObject. It returns YES if two object pointers are the same, and NO if they are not. If you want a different result, you need to override isEqual for your Box class. Note that the argument to isEqual: could be anything, not just a Box, so you need to be careful.

Obviously you shouldn't declare instance variables put properties, so the code below assumes that. The way your code is written, you will have some confusion with an instance variable height, a property height, and an instance variable _height, which will give you headaches. It also assumes that you are not subclassing Box (for example you could have a coloured box, which should not be equal to a Box with same width, height and breadth).

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other
{
    if (! [other isKindOfClass:[Box class]]) return NO;
    Box* otherBox = other;
    return _length == other.length && _breadth == other.breadth 
           && _height == other.height;
}
```